# Pagination links appear as dots in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement pagination in vue. The issue I am facing here is that the pagination links appear as dots as shows in the image attached. The number of pagination links that appear are correct. I am able to navigate on different pages using the side navigation arrows on the pagination links (<,>). I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Help me figure out this issue.

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-app class="abilities">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="users"
      hide-actions
      class="user-table"
      v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.description }}</td>
      </template>
      <template slot="no-data" >
        <v-alert id='no-data' :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
          No User Yet
        </v-alert>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <v-layout row wrap v-if="this.users.length > 5">
      <v-flex xs12>
        <div class="user-pagination">
          <v-pagination v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages"></v-pagination>
        </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      pagination: {
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        page: 1
      },
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Date',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Description',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
      ],
      users: [],
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    var that = this;

    this.fetchUsers();
  },
    computed: {
    pages () {
      return this.pagination.rowsPerPage ? Math.ceil(this.users.length / this.pagination.rowsPerPage) : 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUsers() {
      var url = '/users.json?';
      this.$axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
          let data = response.data;
          let users = [];
          data.map((user, index) => {
            let expandedData = user;

            users.push(expandedData)
          });

          this.users = users;
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you `Inspect` with your browser F12, does those `...` value in DOM shown as number or same `...` ? This seems to `ellipsis` text case (could be at server, or front-end)

Comment: This issue is fixed on changing the browser size. Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: I think this is likely Vuetify gimmicks: 

"Using the length prop you can set the length of v-pagination, if the number of page buttons exceeds the parent container, it will truncate the list."

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/

Comment: I am already using the length prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the computed property, it is returning an `Infinity`  and `NaN` in some cases:

When `this.pagination.rowsPerPage` is `0` you are doing:

`return Math.ceil(this.users.length / 0)`

returns `infinity`,

and when `this.users.length` is `0` you have:

`return Math.ceil(0 / 0)`

returns `NaN`

and so you get the ...

This should do:

```js
computed: {
  pages () {
    return this.pagination.rowsPerPage && this.users.lenght!= 0 ? Math.ceil(this.users.length / this.pagination.rowsPerPage) : 0
  }
},
```

Comment: still the same. I tried your solution but it is not fixed.

Comment: still no change. same issue.

Comment: Actually it was my fault. I am using pagination with v-tabs. Adding lazy to v-tabs fixed the issue